# Table not showing up in SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have created a table `Persons`, but it is not showing neither in object explorer of SQL Server Management Studio, nor in connection properties but queries are running on `Persons` FB any idea? P.S I am new to SQL Server

[image: Persons not there]

[image: Persons database not here either]

I have created the database table with this

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
( 
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    LastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    FirstName VARCHAR(255), 
    Age INT, 
    City VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Punjab' 
);
```

and then insert query

Comment: In object explorer, right click on 'databases' and click 'refresh'. For intellisense to pick up on new db/schema objects, just close out of SSMS all together and reopen it.

Comment: @Mallorie i have tried that earlier doing so results in db llost i have to create again then

Comment: What version SSMS? Have you tried Ctrl+Shift+R or Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache?

Comment: @Mallorie yes i have tried that and i am using 12.0 version

Comment: Please edit your question with more details then. How you created the db, who you created it as, who you're logged in as, what you've already tried, example scripts, etc. Too vague to answer.

Comment: @Mallorie i have done that Please check

Comment: What you have created is a `table`, not a `db`. Since your query was run under the `users` schema in your image, I'm assuming that's the schema it was created under.  Expand the `users` db in Object Explorer, then expand `Tables`. That's where it likely exists. If not, check the others.

Comment: Yes you were right i was not creating in master thanks a lot @Mallorie

Comment: Welcome. And since you're new to sql, so I don't confuse you with wrong terms, I used `schema` incorrectly in my reply.  I meant database, not schema (which means something totally different in SQL Server than in the db I usually use).

Comment: you do not want to create tables in the master database. this is a system database that you generally shouldn't add user objects to.